# WP7 - set ListBoxItem.IsSelected to true from c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox with multiple ListBoxItems. I want to set some of these to 'selected'. I am trying the following but it does not work:

```
ListBoxItem1.IsSelected = true;
```

The result is that it compiles with no error, but the list item remains unselected.

Any ideas?
many thanks!
will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I can't attest to why that happens and if it is a WP7 thing as the docs clearly state:

> To select a ListBoxItem in a ListBox, set this property to true.

However, you can always use the [ListBox.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property:

```
// to add
listBox.SelectedItems.Add( someItem );

// to remove
listBox.SelectedItems.Remove( someItem );

// to clear
listBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

If multi-select is not enabled you can simply use the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and/or the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) properties.

Comment: Is it possible to set SelectedItems from the viewmodel?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko: Possible?  Of course, you can write your code however you like.  It would be a bad idea though.  Your viewmodel should not be tied to specific UI controls (or anything in the UI at all).  That's the point of separating the view from the model in the first place.

Comment: @EdS. I'm talking about by-design "possibility". :) Ok, so what i need is to have a control over SelectedItems from ViewModel: it contains a list of tags, so when user selects one item, all unselected items should be removed, and new ones are added from the server answer. When user selects second tag, again, all unselected tags should be removed. Also, if page is tombstoned, selected items should be restored. So, i should have access to SelectedItems from ViewModel. I also considered using messages from VM to View, and keep SelectedItems in the View, but i dont really like this idea.